# this.props.navigation is not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the ff stacknavigation on my App.js:

```
<NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={'BookListing'}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Book List" component={Tabs} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="BookDetailScreen"
              component={BookDetail}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

Now on my BookList Screen file, I created an onPressHandler function so I can navigate on the details screen and probably pass the data from redux state.

```
class BookListingScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchBooks();
  }

  onPressHandler = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('BookDetailScreen');
  };

  render() {
    let content = (
      <BookList
        onPress={this.onPressHandler}
        books={this.props.randomBooks.books}
      />
    );
    if (this.props.randomBooks.isFetching) {
      content = <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>{renderHeader()}</View>
        <View>{content}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my book list component:

```
export default class BookList extends Component {
  _keyExtractor = item => item.cover_i;
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={{flex: 1}}
        data={this.props.books}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={({item} = this.props.books) => {
          return (
            <BookItem onPressHandler={this.props.onPressHandler} item={item} />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now on my item list, I am trying to use a `TouchableOpacity` to go the Details Screen.

```
export default class BookItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {title, author_name, oclc = []} = this.props.item;
    const onPressHandler = this.props.onPressHandler;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressHandler}>
        <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
          <View style={{paddingRight: 5}}>
            <Text style={styles.cardTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't go to the Details Screen. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Where are you calling `BookItem` component?

Comment: On my books list screen I am passing my props like this `BookList` -> `BookItem` so the touchable must be on the `BookItem` since that's where each single list are coded.

Comment: Share your <BookList /> component code as well.

Comment: Ok I just updated my code

Comment: I think below answer will fix the issue. I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this in BookItem

```
onPress={() => onPressHandler}
```

to this

```
onPress={() => onPressHandler()}
```

or

```
onPress={onPressHandler}
```

Comment: where is book listing screen in the stack

Comment: I assigned the Book Listing Screen as the Tab component should I create a separate one just for Book Listing Screen?

Comment: `<Stack.Screen name="Book List" component={Tabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name="BookListing" component={BookListingScreen} />`

Comment: Ok Ok I figure it out. However, I have one question, where do I pass the data? should I pass it on the Screen Level or on the Component Level? Like on the FlatList?

Comment: Update your question with current code. You have `Tabs` component and it contains `BookListingScreen ` and that contains `BookList`, is that right?